# Regular Expression to find the question in the string

Tags: c#, regex

## I have some string like this,

> \r\n21.what is your favourite pet
>   name?\r\nA.Cat B.Dog\r\nC.Horse
>   D.Snake\r\n22.Which country produce
>   wheat most?\r\nA.Australia
>   B.Bhutan\r\nC.India D.Canada.

=====================================

Now i have to find the questions as well as the choice from the string through regular expression.

Can anybody sujjest.

I am  parsing like `[1-9][.]` for the question. But I am getting two questions sometimes merged.

Can any body suggest any changes.

Comment: are there always 4 choices for an answer?

Comment: [1-9]{1}[0-9]?[.]  you'll probably need more than that but that should match the numbers better

Comment: @scott: You don't need the `{1}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
((\d+\..*?\?\\r\\n)(A\..*?)(B\..*?)(C\..*?)(D\..*?\\r\\n))
```

You can use this regex, but it assumes that after the last choice there are \r\n characters.

Comment: Ok .. I am trying with this..Can you please provide the full notation ... I am using C# regular expression.

Comment: @Ashish, I do not know c#, this regex has been tested rad http://www.radsoftware.com.au/?from=RegexDesigner

Answer (score 1):

I have created two possible regular expressions, depending on if you want the number/letter of the question/answer to appear in the capture or not.

```
Pattern1: (?<Question>\d+\.[^?]+\?)(?:(?:\W*)(?<Answer>[ABCD]\..*?(?=$|(?:\s|\r\n)(?:[ABCD]\.|\d+\.))))*
Pattern2: \d+\.(?<Question>[^?]+\?)(?:(?:\W*)[ABCD]\.(?<Answer>.*?(?=$|(?:\s|\r\n)(?:[ABCD]\.|\d+\.))))*
```

I am assuming you want this in C#, since you tagged it as C#, so here is some sample code you can paste into a new Console Application to begin playing with:

```
        var input = "\r\n21.what is your favourite pet name?\r\nA.Cat B.Dog\r\nC.Horse D.Snake\r\n22.Which country produce wheat most?\r\nA.Australia B.Bhutan\r\nC.India D.Canada.";
        var pattern1 = @"(?<Question>\d+\.[^?]+\?)(?:(?:\W*)(?<Answer>[ABCD]\..*?(?=$|(?:\s|\r\n)(?:[ABCD]\.|\d+\.))))*";
        var pattern2 = @"\d+\.(?<Question>[^?]+\?)(?:(?:\W*)[ABCD]\.(?<Answer>.*?(?=$|(?:\s|\r\n)(?:[ABCD]\.|\d+\.))))*";
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern2))
        {
            var question = m.Groups["Question"].Value;
            var answers = (from Capture cap in m.Groups["Answer"].Captures
                           select cap.Value).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("Question: {0}", question);
            foreach (var answer in answers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Answer: {0}", answer);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

It uses a regex pattern to parse each question into a question variable, and the related answers into a list of answers. You can change which pattern is used by changing the pattern sent to the Regex.Matches() function in the first foreach.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ondrej. It worked to find out my questions perfectly. But still the answer is not parsing. I think this might help you to see my situation . Here is my string

Comment: after" \r\n" the question no. is with the (.). After the "?\r\n k." is the option no. "Sup" is the super script. We do not consider this now.

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

Find the questions:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'[1-9][1-9]*\.([^?]*)',s)
['what is your favourite pet name', 'Which country produce wheat most']
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help:

```
[0-9]+\.(.*?)\?\s*A\.(.*?)\s*B\.(.*?)\s*C\.(.*?)\s*D\.(.*?)\r\n
```

using \r\n to delim questions is not a good idea. Though it should work in your case.

Comment: I am using C#. How to assign this regex for testing. Compiler is givving error.

Comment: @Ashish if you show what compiler is showing it can help. I can't see any errors in this regex, I didn't use regex for C# but this is pretty basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will work in Bengali, but the following code works OK in English (at least on the example you provided ;) ):

```
var input = "\r\n21.what is your favourite pet name?\r\nA.Cat B.Dog\r\nC.Horse D.Snake\r\n22.Which country produce wheat most?\r\nA.Australia B.Bhutan\r\nC.India D.Canada.";

var regex = new Regex(@"(?<number>[0-9]+)\.(?<question>.+\?)\W+((?<letter>[A-Z])\.(?<answer>\w+)\W*)+");

foreach (Match question in regex.Matches(input))
{
    Console.Write("{0}. ", question.Groups["number"].Captures[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(question.Groups["question"].Captures[0]);

    foreach (Capture answer in question.Groups["answer"].Captures)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(answer.Value);
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
21. what is your favourite pet name?
Cat
Dog
Horse
Snake
22. Which country produce wheat most?
Australia
Bhutan
India
Canada
```

I guess you can get what you need from there.

Comment: Here is text in english. Its not parsing.  "\r\nPage- 1\r\n8. what is the temperature of water in antartica ?  \r\n A. – 273 K üB. 273 K C. 373 K D. K\r\n9. Which are the core color? \r\n A. red, blue, green B. white, yellow, green\r\nü C. reg, gray, yellow D. White  and Pink\r\n10. What is the specific heat of water ?  \r\n A. 400 Jkg<sup>–1</sup>K<sup>–1   </sup>B. 800 Jkg<sup>–1</sup>K<sup>–1</sup>\r\n C. 4000 Jkg<sup>–1   </sup>üD. 4200 Jkg<sup>–1</sup>K<sup>–1</sup>\r\n20. What is the unit of resistance ? \r\n A. Ohom               B.  Volt  \r\n      C. joule           D. Kelvin\r\n";

Comment: hmm... yes, indeed, the input changed quite a bit... I notice there's now a concept of pages, how should that be handled? Is there a rule as to how answers are separated? It seems to be quite random (sometimes there are spaces, sometimes new lines, sometimes nothing at all...) There also some weird 'ü' characters in the string, are those normal?